# Why is the instruction to swap stderr with stdout backward?

Tags: stdout, swap, stderr, io-redirection

In numerouse places, I've found people suggesting that you can swap stderr with stdout as follows:

command 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3

This looks backwards to me.  If we send 3 to 2 and then immediately send 2 to 1 (which now would appear to be sending both 3 and 2 to 1).  I think there's something basic I don't understand about IO redirection, but I can't find anything which clarifies it.

Comment: I saw that link.  It doesn't answer why things look backward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find a detailed explanation at http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/ , section 21:

> $ command 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 Here we first duplicate file descriptor 3 to
>   be a copy of stdout. Then we duplicate stdout to be a copy of stderr,
>   and finally we duplicate stderr to be a copy of file descriptor 3,
>   which is stdout. As a result we've swapped stdout and stderr.

There is more detail, and pictures, at the link given. The key insight is:

`3>&1` means "3 points to where 1 is pointing". Then `1>&2` says "now 1 points to where 2 is pointing" (1 now points to stream 2, but 3 doesn't follow...), and finally `2>&3` says "now 2 points to where 3 is pointing (which is stream 1).

Graphically (but see link - it's much better than my ascii-art):

```
0 --> /dev/tty0
1 --> /dev/tty1
2 --> /dev/tty2
```

After `3>&1`:

```
0 --> /dev/tty0
1 --> /dev/tty1
2 --> /dev/tty2
3 --> /dev/tty1
```

After `1>&2`:

```
0 --> /dev/tty0
1 --> /dev/tty2
2 --> /dev/tty2
3 --> /dev/tty1
```

After `2>&3`:

```
0 --> /dev/tty0
1 --> /dev/tty2
2 --> /dev/tty1
3 --> /dev/tty1
```

As you can see, `1` and `2` have been swapped. The same link recommends closing temporary stream `3` with `3>&-`

Comment: Thanks, I like the pictures with the boxes.  This makes a lot more sense to me than the other ones I found.

Comment: @dspyz I agree - the pictures at the link made things much clearer. I just copied the essence, but can't claim the credit for this cleverness.

Answer (score 1):

Huh, I've never seen that .... anyway ...it seems that is essentially saying firstly ... send 3 to the address of 2 .... then send two to the address of 1 .... then send one to the address of 3...which from the first step, we know is the original address of two ... so you've swapped them .... haven't tested that out myself though....

Answer (score 0):

The reason it looks backwards is because it *is* backwards.

When you see `2>&1` it looks like it's sending stderr (2) to stdout (1). And it seems to work that way, in that data written by the program to stderr arrives at the next program in a pipeline on stdin. But that's not how it's implemented. The implementation assigns the contents of the stdout file descriptor (1) to the stderr file descriptor (2), so that when the program writes to either stderr or stdout, the data goes to the same place.

Let's invent an alternate, fictitious syntax. File descriptors are variables with names `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`, `fd3`, `fd4`, etc, and assignment goes right to left in the conventional manner.

A normal assignment in our fictitious syntax, `stderr = stdout` corresponds to the "backwards" shell syntax `2>&1`. Because `>` points to the right, it looks like the assignment goes to the right, right? Wrong. It's a right to left assignment.

So the confusing, backward-seeming `3>&2 2>&1 1>&3` becomes a straightforward swap through a temporary variable:

```
fd3 = stderr
stderr = stdout
stdout = fd3
```

Adding `3>&-` to close the temporary is analogous to adding `fd3 = null`